# Coupon Collection Random Sum

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, combinatorics, coupon-collector-problem

I have a problem which involves the standard coupon collector's problem to find a probability density from the generating convolution. I start by defining the problem and a few basic statistics. Let the number of unique coupons be $N$, numbered from $1$ to $N$. Our goal is to collect each unique coupon **at least once**.

---

I want to find the probability distribution of $$T=\sum\limits_{i=1}^R X_i$$ where

- $X_i$ is the number of the coupon in the $i$-th draw
- $R$ is the number of draws until all coupons are collected at least once.

---

**Define $R$ to be** the number of draws until we collect **at least 1** of each unique coupon. This is itself a sum of N independent Geometric random variables $Z_i$, with $R=\sum\limits_{i=1}^N Z_i$.

By inclusion-exclusion principles and a little algebra, it is trivial to show $R$ has a probability distribution: $$\mathbb P(R=r)= \frac{N!}{N^r} \times {r-1 \brace N-1}. \quad R\ge N$$

Since $R$ is a sum of independent geometric random variables, it can be shown the probability generating function $g_R(t)$ is $$\mathbb E(t^R) = \prod_{i=1}^N \frac{N - i + 1}{N - (i - 1)t}. \quad |t| \lt \frac{N}{N - 1}$$

**Define $X_i$ to be** the value of the drawn coupon on each of the independent draws. They are i.i.d. with probability distribution $\mathbb P(X_i=x)= \dfrac 1N$, i.e. $X_i$ has a discrete uniform distribution with $ 1\le X_i \le N$. Therefore the probability generating function $\space g_{X_{i}}(t)$ is $$\mathbb E(t^{X_i}) = \frac {t \left({1 - t^N}\right)} {N \left({1 - t}\right)}. \quad |t| \lt 1$$

Therefore the random sum $T=\sum\limits_{i=1}^R X_i$ should have a convoluted probability generating function $$g_R(g_{X_{i}}(t))= \prod_{i=1}^N \frac{N - i + 1}{N - (i - 1) \times \dfrac {t \left({1 - t^N}\right)} {N \left({1 - t}\right)}}, \quad |t| \lt 1$$ which simplifies to
$$\prod_{i=1}^N \frac{N(1-t)(N - i + 1)}{N^2(1-t) - (i - 1) {t \left({1 - t^N}\right)}}.$$

---

I am as new as you can get to this site so sorry if I buggered something up! Never worked with latex so feel free to change any errors I made. Hopefully this is a fulfilling and interesting question and someone can find a naughty method. Given what I am doing is right (oops if I made a silly error and the answer is cat), if anyone can help with this fun looking convolution (I have chucked a few things at it and resulted in poop) it would be awesome! I have also tried it from first principles through computing $\mathbb P(T=t)$ using combinatorics and compositions but it seems I would need to read up a bit about A-restricted compositions, mostly of which I am having trouble getting my head around. Then again, I am stuck here too. Please help. Much appreciated. :)

Links below are just formality for those unfamiliar with the base problem.

The standard coupon collector's problem as can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

The term in the braces for the distribution of $R$ is the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

## Edit 1

Having thought about it for a few days, it seems this problem MAY be able to be done by the law of total probability. However I am still restricted by conditions on the collection, i.e. the number of each coupon collected should be at least $1$ to successfully complete the total. Let me explain:

$$\mathbb P(T=t)= \sum_i \mathbb P(T=t \mid R=i) \mathbb P(R=i),$$ where

$$i \in \left[ \bigg \lceil {\frac {T- \frac {N(N+1)}2}N} \bigg \rceil +N,N+ T-\frac {N(N+1)}2 \right]$$

So all we need is away to get $\mathbb P(T=t \mid R=i)$ for all $i$. And I know this can be achieved by finding: (1) How many ways in exactly $i-1$ steps we can get a total of $T-j$ for each for each $j \in [1,N]$, and divide it by: (2) the number of ways to finish in $i$ such that each number is rolled at least once **not before** collection step $i$.

Lets think about the case $N=6$ (a fir 6-sided dice) and $T=22$ It is clear our limits for $i$ are from $[\max(6,1)+1,6+1]=[7,7]$, which this implies the only way to achieve total of $22$ where we roll every number from $1 \to 6$ at least once is in exactly $7$ rolls. Hopefully we can see that is the case intuitively.

So (1) is calculated by all the permutations of $22-j$ without $j$ for each $j  \in [1,6]$ and (2) is calculated by all the permutations of finishing in $R=i$ goes, independent of finishing on a total of $22$.

My issue is then calculating (1) and (to some extent without high knowledge of A-restricted compositions) (2)!

## Edit 2

I found a closed form for the simplest case N=2. Which is just a coin. With one side labeled a $1$. The other having a $2$.

$X_i$ is discrete uniform with $P(X_i=1)=1-P(X_i=2)=\frac 12$. I want to get $P(T=t)$ for $T \ge3$.

Let $T=3$. By counting, we can roll a total of 3 by:
$$(1,2) \ \ OR \ \ (2,1)$$
Either event has probability $\left( \frac 12 \right)^2$. So we have $P(T=3)=2\left( \frac 12 \right)^2=\left( \frac 12 \right)$

Let $T=4$. By counting, we can roll a total of 4 by:
$$(1,1,2)$$
This event has probability $\left( \frac 12 \right)^3$. So we have $P(T=4)=\left( \frac 18 \right)$

Here we **do not** count the event $(2,1,1)$ as a total of $4$ since by the second roll we have successfully achieved $D$. hence the actual total would be $3$ and we ignore the final $1$.

Now, let $T=5$. By counting, we can roll a total of 5 by:
$$(1,1,1,2) \ \ OR \ \ (2,2,1)$$
The first event has probability $\left( \frac 12 \right)^4$. The second event has probability $\left( \frac 12 \right)^3$ So we have $P(T=5)=\left( \frac 12 \right)^4+ \left( \frac 12 \right)^3$

If we continue in this fashion, we will always have exactly 2 ways of rolling a total of $T=t$. One with probability to the power of $T-\sum_{i=1}^2i=T-3$ and the other with probability to the power of $\frac {T-3}2$ when T is odd and $0$ if even. We can hence write down the closed form for the simplest case where $N=2$ as: $$P(T=t|N=2)=\frac 14 \left(\left(\frac 12 \right)^{t-3}+\Bbb I_{t \ is \ odd} \left(\frac 12 \right)^{\frac{t-3}2} \right)$$

But of course this still leaves me with not knowing $N=3,4,5,...$

## Edit 3

The basic statistics for this problem follow from the definitions of $R$ and $X_i$. Firstly:
$$\Bbb E(T)=\Bbb E(\sum\limits_{i=1}^R X_i)$$.

It is known that:
$$\Bbb E(R)=N\ \sum\limits_{i=1}^N E(Z_i)=NH_N$$

for $H_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^N \frac 1i$ the harmonic number.

Since $X_i$ is uniform: $$\Bbb E(X_i)=\frac {N+1}2 \ \ \forall i$$

Putting it all together using *Wald's identity* we get:
$$\Bbb E(T)=\Bbb E(R)\Bbb E(X_i)=N\sum\limits_{i=1}^N \frac 1i \frac {N+1}2$$
$$=\frac 12 N(N+1) \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \frac 1i$$

Next lets consider the variance:
$$\Bbb V(T)=\Bbb V(\sum\limits_{i=1}^R X_i)$$

It is also known that (from properties of i.i.d. geometric random variables):
$$\Bbb V(R)=N\sum\limits_{i=1}^N \frac {i-1}{(N-i+1)^2}$$

Since $X_i$ is uniform:
$$\Bbb V(X_i)=\frac {N^2-1}{12} \ \ \forall i$$

Now using the identity for the variance of a random sum via law of iterated variance:
$$\Bbb V(T)=\Bbb E(R) \Bbb V(X_i) + [\Bbb E(X_i)]^2 \Bbb V(R)$$
$$=N \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \frac 1i \frac {N^2-1}{12}+\frac {(N+1)^2}4 \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \frac {N(i-1)}{(N-i+1)^2}$$
$$=\frac {N(N+1)(N-1)}{12} \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \frac 1i+\frac {N(N+1)(N+1)}4 \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \frac {i-1}{(N-i+1)^2}$$
$$=\frac {N(N+1)}{12} \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \left[ \frac {N-1}i + \frac {3(N+1)(i-1)}{(N-i+1)^2} \right]$$

So for example when $N=6$, i.e. a die:
$$\Bbb E(T)=\frac 12 6(6+1) \sum\limits_{i=1}^6 \frac 1i=51.45$$
$$\Bbb V(T)=\frac {6(7)}{12} \sum\limits_{i=1}^6 \left[ \frac {5}i + \frac {3(7)(i-1)}{(6-i+1)^2} \right]=\frac {42}{12} 148.715= 520.5025$$

This makes sense. On average we roll $14.7$ times and get $3.5$ on each roll. $14.7 \cdot 3.5=51.45$.

In fact, a simulation of $10$ million collections shows that these are the correct values:

```
> mean(Test$Roll_Total)
[1] 51.45751
> var(Test$Roll_Total)
[1] 520.5317
```

And the following diagram shows the distribution for the total $T$:

[image: N=6]

**Aside**: I have been trying to read up on generating functions for compositions and I cannot quite find what I am looking for in terms of restrictions. If someone finds one please let me know!

Help / hints appreciated :)

Comment: Cross Link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795397/random-sum-in-coupon-collection

Comment: What is the problem? It is very difficult to read and dig trough all this material without knowing what it is leading to. Can't you write *at the top* a concise question, e.g. like a sentence that ends in a question mark? Mathematics problems are often easily described in a few short sentences. E.g. *"proof that $x^n + y^n = z^n$, with $x,y,z,n \in \mathbb{N}$, has no solutions for $n>2$"*

Comment: I changed it myself now. I hope this is ok.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I am writing a partial answer which is to be updated later*

You can use  $$P(T=t|R=r) = \frac{N_{T=t,R=r}}{N_{R=r}}$$

the ratio of $N_{R=r}$ the number of ways the number of ways to finish in $r$ turns and $N_{T=t,R=r}$ the number of ways to finish in $r$ turns *and* the sum $T=t$.

You have

$$N_{R=r} = n^r \cdot P(R=r)$$

thus

$$P(T=t) = \sum_{r \geq n} P(T=t|R=r) P(R=r) = \sum_{r \geq n} \frac{N_{T=t,R=r}}{n^r} $$

---

Now one still needs to solve $N_{T=t,R=r}$ which is like a combinatorial problem. This is a bit more tricky but it could possibly be solved along the lines of [the inductive solution in this simpler question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/31585/466748).